# Using QtimerEvent in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, animation, timer

The timerEvent, which is a member of a QGLWidget class shall be triggered when the mousemove-function is called. I thought I could do it like this:

```
void GLWidget::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e)
{
    if (e->timerId()==1 && refresh==true)
    {
        refresh = !refresh;
        swapBuffers();
        update();
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

```
void OpenGLScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    int mousex = event->scenePos().x();
    int mousey = event->scenePos().y();

    if ((test->modus==2) && (test->move1 != -1))
    {
        p_list[test->move1].x=mousex-(1220);
        p_list[test->move1].y=mousey-( 610);
        test->refresh = !(test->refresh);
        test->timerEvent(???);
        update();
    }
}
```

But somehow I dont know what to put into where the questions marks are. I have tried several things. It is not working. I want to set timerId()=1.
Thanks for your help...

Comment: Why are you trying to use a timer event at all?  QObject's timer event system is generally for executing code periodically over a time interval.  Here you're just trying to execute some code every time the mouse moves.  Also, you can't control the id of the timer event, Qt manages them for you (see [the QObject::startTimer() documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#startTimer)).

Answer (score 0):

why don't you call your own event like :

```
void OpenGLScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    // ...
    if ((test->modus==2) && (test->move1 != -1))
    {
        // ...
        test->refresh = !(test->refresh);

        //test->timerEvent(???); replaced by :
        test->manuelUpdate(); // your own function
        //...
    }
}
```

and in your GLWidget :

```
void GLWidget::manuelUpdate()
{
    if (refresh==true)
    {
        refresh = !refresh;
        swapBuffers();
        update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The timer-function is an equivalent to the idle-function in OpenGL. Yes the code should be called whenever the mouse moves. Because I am grabing points with my mouse and move them with that function.

Comment: Actually its working fine... I only had a minor problem with my coordinates.Thanks anyway